# Access TFS from workstation that is not on a domain

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

Ok, so this is a little crazy:

I'm setting up an eval of TFS (not my first rodeo with TFS though -- just at a new place).

I have a VM server (server 2008r2/sp1, domain member)

I have a VM client running Visual Studio (Windows 7/SP1, not on the domain)

From the client, when I attempt to connect with either Visual Studio (2013/update4) or if I use IE11 to hit TFS Web Access, I am challenged for credentials (expected), but when I put in my domain creds, I get a 401!

However, if I use Chrome from the same VM to hit web access, I am challenged (expected), and my domain creds get me right in!

So:
Since it works with chrome, I have to assume that the vm is successfully connecting to the server, and that my account is set up with proper access to TFS.

However, I can't seem to fathom why it doesn't work from IE, or (more importantly), from Visual Studio.

Using TFS 2013/Update 4, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

In a bout of desperation, I ran windows update, and applied all updates, including the optional ones.  Solved. (or is that "Solved?")

For future reference, I did find this post while the updates were running.  This would have been my next attempt: https://serverfault.com/questions/151753/integrated-windows-authentication-not-working-in-ie-only